# Compute associations between a rare variant in one individual and gene expression levels

Tags: logistic, genetics, association-measure

Is it possible to compute an association between gene expression levels measured in many individuals and a polymorphism, when only one individual has the polymorphism versus all the other individuals without that polymorphism? Would it be wrong to use regression in this case? Are there are tests that have been developed for these cases?